# Проблема с ItemCollection в ListBox (доступ к элементу по индексу)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть ListBox. В определенный момент выполняется кусок кода, увеличивающий `SelectedIndex` на единицу. Естественно, сначала проверяется такая возможность, путем сравнения с `Items.Count`. И тут начинается веселье. Вылетает исключение

*Заданный аргумент находится вне диапазона допустимых значений*

Начинаю разбираться. Смотрю в отладке контрольные значения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иду дальше и пытаюсь посмотреть набор коллекции и вижу вот что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните мне, это как? `Count` == 2, но при этом доступа к элементу с индексом 1 нет. Кто сталкивался?

Comment: Количество может быть равно 2, но не факт, что остальные элементы инициализированы. Могу ошибаться, но если ты создашь List<T> на 10 элементов и обратишься к не инициализрованному элементу, то получишь такую же ошибку.

Comment: @iluxa1810, нет, если ты обратишься к неинициализированному элементу, то получишь null.

Comment: @iRumba, а как коллекция заполняется?

Comment: @iRumba: А дайте воспроизводящий пример. Может вы это делаете в каком-нибудь обработчике события, кто ж знает.

Comment: @VladD, не совсем в обработчике... я это делаю по команде. На самом деле у меня появилась идея, почему так произошло, но времени нет проверить. Происходит следующее. Листбок биндится к CollectionView с фильтром от основной коллекции. При выполнении команды происходит 2 действия в разных событиях. 1 - у элемента коллекции меняется свойство, по которому фильтруется вьюха и элемент из коллекции пропадает. 2 - индекс сдвигается на 1. Но Count, видимо, среагировать на первое действие не успевает (что странно, это ведь явно баг получается).

Comment: @iRumba: Может быть, команда вызывается «по дороге»? На что вы её навешиваете?

Comment: @VladD На нажатие кнопочки )